# Parse/force UIViewController to be my custom viewcontroller Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift3

I am not quite familiar with swift 3 syntax.

In objective-c, we write like this to parse.

```
NewsfeedVC *vc = (NewsfeedVC *)viewController;
```

How can I write for swift 3?

Comment: let vc: NewsfeedVC = viewController as! NewsfeedVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a Converter

[Objective-C to Swift](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/)

And the above code in Swift will be like:

```
var vc: NewsfeedVC? = (viewController as? NewsfeedVC)
```